# jQuery UI Modal Form Not Working - DIV Won't Hide, Button Does Nothing

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have code that doesn't want to work, though I essentially mirrored one of my functional pages.  I've been banging on this since last night and I can't see what's wrong.  Can someone look at this and help me figure out why it's broken?

**HTML Button**

```
<td><input type="button" class="button" value="Add Location" id="AddLoc" style="width: 141px; text-align: center;"></td>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#AddLoc').click(function () {
    var setLoc = function () {
        var n = $('#LocName').val();
        var a1 = $('#LocAddr1').val("");
        var a2 = $('#LocAddr2').val("");
        var c = $('#LocCity').val("");
        var z = $('#LocZip').val("");

        $.post('/jqf/hvsr_processajax.php', {N: n, A1: a1, A2: a2, C: c, Z: z}, function (data) {
            $(#'HVLoc').replaceWith(data);
        });
    }

    var cancel = function () {
        $('#LocName').val("");
        $('#LocAddr1').val("");
        $('#LocAddr2').val("");
        $('#LocCity').val("");
        $('#LocZip').val("");
        $("#AddLocForm").dialog("close");
    };

    var dialogOpts = {
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": setLoc,
            "Cancel": cancel
        },
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 550,
    };

    $('#AddLocForm').css("display", "block");
    $('#AddLocForm').dialog(dialogOpts);
});
$('#AddLocForm').css("display", "none");
```

**HTML DIV**

```
<div id="AddLocForm" title="Add Missing Location To CHAIRS Database"">
    <form style="margin:5px; border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; background-color: #FAFAFA;">
        <fieldset style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0; padding: 10px; width: 460px;">
            <legend>Complete Form To Add Location</legend>
            <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; border:2px solid #253183; width: 100%; max-width: 480px;">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; background: #4F82CB; color: #FFFFFF; padding:2px 2px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;">Location Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color: black; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;"><input class="input" type="text" name="hvlocationName" id="LocName" style="width: 423px"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; background: #4F82CB; color: #FFFFFF; padding:2px 2px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;">Address 1</th>
    <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; background: #4F82CB; color: #FFFFFF; padding:2px 2px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;">Address 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color: black; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;"><input class="input" type="text" name="hvlocationAddr1" id="LocAddr1" style="width: 200px"/></td>
    <td style="font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color: black; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;"><input class="input" type="text" name="hvlocationAddr2" id="LocAddr2" style="width: 200px"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; background: #4F82CB; color: #FFFFFF; padding:2px 2px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;">City</th>
    <th style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; background: #4F82CB; color: #FFFFFF; padding:2px 2px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;">Zip Code</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color: black; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;"><input class="input" type="text" name="hvlocationCity" id="LocCity" style="width: 100px"/></td>
    <td style="font-size:14px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; padding:10px 5px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color: black; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;"><input class="input" type="text" name="hvlocationZipCode" id="LocZip" style="width: 100px"/></td>
</tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you so much everyone!!!

Comment: All your lines like this: `var a1 = $('#LocAddr1').val("");` are wrong. When you give an argument to `.val()`, it sets the value, it doesn't return it.

Comment: You have an extra double quote at the end of `title="Add Missing Location To CHAIRS Database""`. That's messing up all the HTML.

Comment: You can use `$("#AddLocForm").serialize()` to get all the inputs from the form, instead of all those `.val()` calls.

Comment: You are all correct, and I feel dumb.  Guess 2 hours of sleep a night for the last week has made me kind of slow on the upswing.  Stupid deadlines... thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several little errors.

1. `<div id="AddLocForm" title="Add Missing Location To CHAIRS Database"">` has an extra `"` at the end.
2. All the lines like `var a1 = $('#LocAddr1').val("");` should not have the `""` argument. This is setting the value instead of retrieving it.
3. `$(#'HVLoc').replaceWith(data);` the `#` should be inside the quotes. This was causing a syntax error in the Javascript console, I don't know how you missed it.

When I fix these errors, your code works:

http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oy6dtsd2/2/

Comment: Working on an upcoming deadline, 2 hours of sleep a night for the last week... thanks for the extra eyes!